# How to reset a graph in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

If I use one of the graph tools, typically I don't get the results I want by changing settings and need to use the Direct Selection tool to move/change some things around.

Sometimes I want to revert back to the original vanilla graph and Illustrator made it before I started started changing. For example, if I move labels around on a pie chart and then change the legend location in the settings, my changes to the labels doesn't reset.

Is there a way to reset a graph? My current work around is copy/paste the data into a new chart.